# Пробуждение приложения

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток господа.
Есть у меня приложение которое мониторит состояние сервера и мне нужно когда сервер перестает отвечать сообщить об этом пользователю, но как это сделать ? Когда блокирую телефон или сворачиваю приложение получаю ошибку.

Насколько я понял, мне нужно как-то "пробудить телефон", но "нагуглить" ничего не смог ибо даже не знаю как это сформулировать.

```
public void startAlarm()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), main_activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.d("SERVER", "test1");
    alarm.show(getFragmentManager(), "Server status");
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Ошибка:

```
12-03 15:48:41.919 14589-14626/com.hikari.dev.servermonitor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6480
Process: com.hikari.dev.servermonitor, PID: 14589
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1438)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1456)
  at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:692)
  at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:668)
  at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230)
  at com.hikari.dev.servermonitor.activity.main_activity.startAlarm(main_activity.java:166)
  at com.hikari.dev.servermonitor.server$1.run(server.java:63)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это

Источник:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621599/wake-android-device-up

---

Для пробуждения экрана

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Для снятия блокировки

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Добавить в манифест соответствующие привелегии

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

PowerManager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html